# Update fails with duplicate row

Tags: sql, teradata

I am teaching myself SQL with a small database I inherited.  While I was playing with Update(),

```
update a
from sls_ord_fact a, sls_ord_dim b
set cust_acct_key = b.cust_acct_key
where a.sls_ord_key = b.sls_ord_key
and a.sls_ord_key <> 0
and b.cust_acct_key <> 0
and a.cust_acct_key <> b.cust_acct_key;
```

I triggered this error :`Duplicate row error in SLS_ORD_FACT`

How can identify the duplicate record??? I don't know the data very well.....

Comment: Teradata v10 is the database. The DBA created a sandbox schema for SQL newbies like me.

Comment: Can you share the table definition or primary index definition?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the primary key of the `SLS_ORD_FACT` table (presumably that is `cust_acct_key`), and the new value you're trying to set it to already exists in the table. Since primary keys must be unique, this causes an error. The duplicate key is in `b` - in fact, it's `b.cust_acct_key`, which is probably a foreign key to `SLS_ORD_FACT.cust_acct_key`.

Comment: What you're saying make sense but I tried to find the duplicate row like this `select a.cust_acct_key,b.cust_acct_key from sls_ord_fact a, sls_ord_dim b where a.sls_ord_key = b.sls_ord_key and a.sls_ord_key <> 0 and b.cust_acct_key <> 0 and a.cust_acct_key <> b.cust_acct_key`
and found zero matches. All keys are different. What am I missing?

Comment: this attempt gave me an even greater number of keys in the sls order dim table that have duplicate counts `SELECT distinct     b.cust_acct_key, COUNT(*) FROM     sls_ord_dim b
    WHERE b.cust_acct_key <> 0 GROUP BY     b.cust_acct_key 
HAVING     COUNT(*) > 1`